# Problems with char initialization

Tags: c++, char

I have some problems with initializating my char variables.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
  class Scout {
    public:
     Scout(char Name,char Surname) : name(Name), surname(Surname) {
       cout << "Constructor 1" << " name = " << name << " surname = " <<surname;
   };
  private:
    char name, surname;
};
  int main()
 {
     Scout Andrew("Duck","Jones");
     system("pause");
     return 0;
  }
```

Error   C2664   'Scout::Scout(Scout &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [5]' to 'char'

Error (active)      no instance of constructor "Scout::Scout" matches the argument list

Is there any other ways to initialize name and surname?

Comment: Both `name` and `surname` are declared as a **single** characters. Best to avoid ugly c-strings and use `std::string`

Comment: avoid using `system("pause")`. Use `cin.get()` instead.

Comment: `char` means *one character*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument types of your constructor are `char` while the arguments you pass here `Andrew("Duck","Jones");` are of type `const char*`. This doesn't work. Because this is C++, you can just use `std::string`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

  class Scout {
    public:
     Scout(std::string Name, std::string Surname) : name(Name), surname(Surname) {
       std::cout << "Constructor 1" << " name = " << name << " surname = " <<surname;
   };
  private:
    std::string name, surname;
};

int main()
{
   Scout Andrew("Duck","Jones");
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```